# How to access private variables

Tags: android

Is there any way to access private variables of other class.Actually I am writing testCases for my library project in order to test all possible critical conditions when the app is going to crash .I shuld write in such a way that my project should pass all test cases.Now what my problem I should check for the variables which are declared as private in my library project.Is there any way to access these variables (which are declared as private).

Comment: A good question - on the one hand you would like you code to be as component-local scoped as possible, on the other the test suite has to have access to the internals. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [getters and setters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) ..it is the preferred way.. in setters make sure you keep safe values and make sure they will not break your code in any case..

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you wanna make your activities' methods private to prevent other classes from thinking they can access it (fragment can, but that is wrong practice to me, it's better to use an observable-observer pattern). Then you will end up with private fields and methods that would need to be accessed by tests only.

[**BoundBox**](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/boundbox) does exactly that ! Here below is an example of a test that accesses 2 private fields of an activity to test it :

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testCompute() {
    // given
    boundBoxOfMainActivity = new BoundBoxOfMainActivity(getActivity());

    // when
    boundBoxOfMainActivity.boundBox_getButtonMain().performClick();

    // then
    assertEquals("42", boundBoxOfMainActivity.boundBox_getTextViewMain().getText());
}
```