# am getting an error as the field is not visible

Tags: java

my intention is to print "FINE IS IMPOSED" in the output, if the balance available is less than the Minimum Balance.
but am getting error as mentioned below.
pl. help me out

```
//Savings Account of a customer by setting and getting MinimumBalance
public class SavingsAccount {
    private int    AccountNumber;
    private String Customer;
    private double Balance;
    private double MinimumBalance;

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param Number
     *         the account's number.
     * @param Name
     *         the account holders name.
     * @param bal
     *         the balance available.
     */
    public void open(int Number, String Name, double bal) {
        AccountNumber = Number;
        Customer = Name;
        Balance = bal;
    }

    /**
     * sets Minimum Balance
     *
     * @param minbal
     *         the Minimum Balance
     */
    public void setMinimumBalance(int minbal) {
        MinimumBalance = minbal;
    }

    /**
     * returning Minimum Balance
     *
     * @return it is returning Minimum Balance
     */
    public double getMinimumBalance() {
        return MinimumBalance;
    }

    /**
     * display the details of savings account
     */
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("The Account Number is:" + (AccountNumber));
        System.out.println("The name of the Customer is :" + (Customer));
        System.out.println("Available balance is :" + (Balance));
        System.out.println("Minimum Balance to be maintained is :"
        (MinimumBalance));
    }
}

// testing of savings account
public class Savings1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SavingsAccount S1; //Object Reference
        S1 = new SavingsAccount(); //Creating Object
        S1.open(256101, "Mr.Gates ", 5000);
        S1.setMinimumBalance(6000);
        S1.print();
        if (S1.Balance < S1.getMinimumBalance()) {
            System.out.println("FINE IS IMPOSED");
        }
    }
}
```

error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation 
        problem: 
 The field SavingsAccount.Balance is not visible
at Savings1.main(Savings1.java:9)

Comment: Some remarks: - you do not need a separate class for your `main(...)`-method, you can simply move the `main(...)` in `SavingsAccount`. - variable names should always start with a lowercase letter (`AccountNumber -> accountNumber,...`) - you should write getter/setter for all your attributes instead of manipulating the attributes directly (`S1.balance -> S1.getBalance()`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190077/how-to-access-private-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class SavingsAccount has an attribute Balance declared as private, that means it is only visible inside that class.

A good approach to access Balance attibute is using a getBalance and call it from other class

```
public double getBalance(){
    return this.Balance;
}
```

And then call getBalance

```
if ( S1.getBalance() < S1.getMinimumBalance())
            System.out.println("FINE IS IMPOSED");
```

Complete version:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
    private int AccountNumber;
    private String Customer;
    private double Balance;
    private double MinimumBalance;
    /**
     * constructor
     * @param Number the account's number.
     * @param Name the account holders name.
     * @param bal the balance available.
     */
    public void open (int Number, String Name,double bal) {
        AccountNumber=Number;
        Customer=Name;
        Balance=bal;
    }
    /**
     * sets Minimum Balance
     * @param minbal the Minimum Balance
     */
    public void setMinimumBalance (int minbal) {
        MinimumBalance=minbal;
    }
    /**
     *  returning Minimum Balance
     * @return it is returning Minimum Balance
     */
    public double getMinimumBalance() {
        return MinimumBalance;
    }
    /**
     * display the details of savings account
     */
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("The Account Number is:" +(AccountNumber));
        System.out.println("The name of the Customer is :" +(Customer));
        System.out.println("Available balance is :" +(Balance));
        System.out.println("Minimum Balance to be maintained is :" +
        (MinimumBalance));
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return this.Balance;
    }
}


// testing of savings account
 class Savings1  {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        SavingsAccount S1; //Object Reference
        S1= new SavingsAccount(); //Creating Object
        S1.open (256101,"Mr.Gates ", 5000);
        S1.setMinimumBalance (6000);
        S1.print();
        if ( S1.getBalance() < S1.getMinimumBalance())
            System.out.println("FINE IS IMPOSED");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

S1.Balance is private, make it public or make a public getter.

Answer (score 0):

Add getter method for Balance and use it instead

```
public double getBalance() {
    return Balance;
}

if (S1.getBalance()< S1.getMinimumBalance()) {
```